# Create a node-link diagram using GWT wrapper for D3.js

Tags: d3.js, gwt, force-layout

I am trying to use the GWT layout of D3.js ([github.com/gwtd3/gwt-d3](https://github.com/gwtd3/gwt-d3)) to create a node-link diagram with a force model. For a start, something even simpler than [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/eyaler/10586116) or [this one](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) would be enough.

But I really have issue to create even the simpler graph using the GWT wrapper. I cannot find how to use the equivalent of the force, node and link objects.

I start with a:

```
Force force = D3.layout().force();
```

But then, I do not know what objects nodes "nodes" and "links" should be and how to initialise them. Their constructors are not visible.

```
force.nodes(nodes).links(links);
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, add additional JSNI convenience methods to create Force.Node and Force.Link instances.

```
/**
 * Convenience function to overcome API limitation. 
 */
static final native <T> Node<T> newNode(T userDatum)/*-{
    return {
        datum : userDatum
    };
}-*/;

/**
 * Convenience function to overcome API limitation. 
 */    
static final native <T> Link<T> newLinkIndex(int source, int target, T userDatum) /*-{
    return {
        source : source,
        target : target,
        datum: userDatum
    };
}-*/;
```

1. Create a GWT D3 'nodes' Array which contains all your Node instances,
2. Initialize a GWT D3 'links' Array which uses indexes (int) from 'nodes' to point to the corresponding Node instances,
3. Apply through invoking: force.nodes(nodes).links(links)

You can see a complete working example in [MobilePatentSuits.java](https://github.com/TOMOTON/gwt-d3/blob/master/gwt-d3-demo/src/main/java/com/github/gwtd3/demo/client/democases/MobilePatentSuits.java)!